# Multiple indexed event fields are not supported by web3j?

Tags: events, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm having Ethereum smart contract with function:

```
event onPledged(uint indexed featureKey, uint date, address backer, uint256 amount);
...
function pledge(uint featureKey) public
    payable
    withState(featureKey, State.Funding)
{
    ...

    // event
    onPledged(featureKey, now, backer, pledgeAmount);

    ...
}
```

I'm having java test (using web3j and web3j-maven-plugin to generate smart contract java wrapper) to call `pledge()` that checks events:

```
    // pledge
    logger.info("Pledging by backer ...");

    TransactionReceipt pledgeReceipt = pledgerContract.pledge(featureKey, fixedPledgeAmount).send();
    List<AppetissimoContract.OnPledgedEventResponse> pledgedEvents = minerContract.getOnPledgedEvents(pledgeReceipt);
    assertEquals(1, pledgedEvents.size()); // true
```

If i change **backer** event field to be `indexed` the test starts to fail:

```
event onPledged(uint indexed featureKey, uint date, address indexed backer, uint256 amount);
```

Now it's fails as there were no events (0):

```
assertEquals(1, pledgedEvents.size()); // false, size() is 0
```

In solidity [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html) it's written that up to 3 fields can be `indexed`:

```
> Up to three parameters can receive the attribute indexed which will cause the respective arguments to be searched for: It is possible to filter for specific values of indexed arguments in the user interface.
```

Is it [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) issue? Does using of `indexed` attribute require more gas (so reaching gas limit can be the reson)?

Comment: I vaguely remember reading somewhere that all of the indexed arguments had to come before non-indexed ones, but I can't find the documentation to back that up (or, I'm not remembering correctly). Have you tried changing the order to put `backer` before `date`?

Comment: No, i did not try it. In examples `indexed` variables are usually the first indeed, but i can't find this in the docs. Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an outstanding [bug](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/209) with web3j. Right now you have to order all of the indexed parameters before the non-indexed parameters to work around this.